# Chat UI library

Tags: javascript, symfony

I am making chat system with [vline](http://vline.com) and symfony2

vline is webRTC platform and API.

I already integreted it with symfony2.

and suceeded in sending messages each client.

However I want to make good UI like Skype.

For this purpose, what kind of approach is best?

Is there any UI library made by HTML5 and Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a vague questions.. but I would suggest [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) when if you want an out of the box solution for defining your UI modelling.